# Proving that $f(x)=3^x$ is one-to-one

Tags: functions

Prove that   $f(x)=3^x$ is injective.
EDIT: The domain of f is the set of all real numbers.

Comment: What have you tried? Do you understand what it means for a function to be one-to-one?

Comment: I think I understand what it means. For example, I can prove that g(x)=6x-9 is one-to-one: 
6a-9 = 6b-9 => 6a = 6b => a = b
But maybe I don't handle some properties to prove f(x)=3^x is one-to-one.

Comment: Not quite sure why this is attracting so many close votes for being "off-topic". Seems a perfectly legitimate mathematical question to me.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** first show that $3^x>3^y$ if $x>y$.

Answer (score 2):

How far down to fundamentals do you need your argument to go? In the beginning before you assume anything about the reals, the only thing you have is that $3^n > 3^m$ when $n > m$ are integers. Then if you assume that you can find roots $3^{1/n}$ for integers $n$, then you can show $3^{p} > 3^q$ when $p > q$ are rationals. Then when $3^x$ is defined in terms of limits $\lim_{n \to \infty} 3^{q_n}$ where $q_n \to x$ is a sequence of rationals, you can show $3^x > 3^y$ when $x > y$ for real numbers $x,y$.

Comment: I edited my question, the domain of f is the set of real numbers.

Comment: And 3^x should not be defined in terms of limits.

Comment: Unfortunately when you delve into the nitty-gritty, you find that can't really define $a^x$ for real $x$ unless you use limits. E.g. what does $3^\pi$ mean if you don't use limits?

Comment: So I can't prove that if $3^x = 3^y$ then x = y ? (without limits, I have not received calculus yet)